# Render table data with head in each row in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to display this table: [image: table format]

like this in react. I have created an array of objects, just like an API

```js
products: [
    {b: "brand1", N: "N1", M: "M1", B: "B1", S: "y1", O: "y1", A: "y1", D: "y1"},
    {b: "brand2", N: "N2", M: "M2", B: "B2", S: "y2", O: "y2", A: "y2", D: "y2"},
    {b: "brand3", N: "N3", M: "M3", B: "B3", S: "y3", O: "y3", A: "y3", D: "y3"},
    {b: "brand4", N: "N4", M: "M4", B: "B4", S: "y4", O: "y4", A: "y4", D: "y4"},
]
```

How can I display this data in my desired format using React?

This is the code which i have tried like this for displaying similar to the picture.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './results.css'

class Results extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
      products: [
        {b: "brand1", N: "N1", M: "M1", B: "B1", S: "y1", O: "y1", A: "y1", D: "y1"},
        {b: "brand2", N: "N2", M: "M2", B: "B2", S: "y2", O: "y2", A: "y2", D: "y2"},
        {b: "brand3", N: "N3", M: "M3", B: "B3", S: "y3", O: "y3", A: "y3", D: "y3"},
        {b: "brand4", N: "N4", M: "M4", B: "B4", S: "y4", O: "y4", A: "y4", D: "y4"},

    }
  }
  renderData = () => {
    return this.state.products.map((product, index)=> {
        const {M, B, S, O, A, D} = product;
        return (
          <div>    
            <tr>
              <th>A</th>
              <td>{ O }</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>F</th>
              <td>{ B }</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>S</th>
              <td>{ S }</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>O</th>
              <td>{ O }</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <th>A</th>
              <td>{ A }</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>D</th>
              <td>{ D }</td>
            </tr>
          </div>
        )
    })
  }

  renderTableHeader = () => {
    return this.state.products.map((product, index)=> {
      const { b } = product;
      return <th>{ b.toUpperCase() }</th>
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.done) {
      return null;
    }

    if (true) {
      return (
          <React.Fragment>
            <div>
              <table id="products">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      { this.renderTableHeader() }
                    </tr>
                  { this.renderData() }
                  </tbody>
              </table>      
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

this is rendering each array into different rows.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Paste your piece of code, then we can help you.

Comment: @mthrsj I have added the code which i have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to transform your data a bit in order to display it in the way you want. Currently, `products` looks to be transposed from the layout you're looking for (although perhaps having each brand be a row rather than a column might be a good idea). We can do this in the `constructor` method (or wherever you handle getting/updating `products`).

After your data is in the right format, it should be more clear how to get the layout you're after. You just need to create a single `tr` element for each row of your data. Each row should contain a single `td` element for each column.

For example:

```js
class Results extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const products = [
            {b: "brand1", N: "N1", M: "M1", B: "B1", S: "y1", O: "y1", A: "y1", D: "y1"},
            {b: "brand2", N: "N2", M: "M2", B: "B2", S: "y2", O: "y2", A: "y2", D: "y2"},
            {b: "brand3", N: "N3", M: "M3", B: "B3", S: "y3", O: "y3", A: "y3", D: "y3"},
            {b: "brand4", N: "N4", M: "M4", B: "B4", S: "y4", O: "y4", A: "y4", D: "y4"},
        ]

        const keys = Object.keys(products[0]).filter(e => e !== "b");

        const formattedProducts = keys.map(key => {
            const row = {key: key};
            for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                const product = products[i];
                row[product.b] = product[key];
            }
            return row;
        });

        this.state = {
            products,
            formattedProducts,
        }
    }

    renderHeader() {
        const { formattedProducts } = this.state;

        const brandNames = products.map(e => e.b);

        return (
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                { brandNames.map(brandName => (
                    <th key={ brandName }>{ brandName }</th>
                )) }
            </tr>
        )
    }

    renderRows() {
        const { formattedProducts } = this.state;

        const brandNames = products.map(e => e.b);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                { formattedProducts.map(row => (
                    <tr key={ row.key }>
                        <td>{ row.key }</td>
                        { brandNames.map(brandName => (
                            <td key={ brandName }>{ row[brandName] }</td>
                        ))}
                    </tr>
                )) }
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                { this.renderHeader() }
                { this.renderRows() }
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```